# How to add IPv6 support in a streaming app that use vitamio and swift?

Tags: swift, ipv6, rtmp, vitamio

I am using vitamio in order to stream video in my app

I have the code below in swift

```
    let url = "rtmp://myurl:1935/live/1"


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true

    player.setupPlayerWithCarrierView(mainView, withDelegate: self)
    player.setDataSource(NSURL(string: url))
    player.prepareAsync()
```

The code above works but It does not support IPv6

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: I did it [ipv6-compatibility](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/) and the result network unreachable, I was trying with getaddrinfo in order to get an ipv6 instead of my url.